# How can I get these two javascript codes to work together?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a form using html.

At first I had it really simple. My input was amount, which a user would enter. I then made javascript code to calculate a dynamic price based on the user's amount input. The code is as follows:

```
<input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Amount" name="Gift-Card Amount"/>
```

The javascript:

```
jQuery("input[name='Gift-Card Amount']").change(function () {

    if (isNaN(parseFloat(this.value)) || !isFinite(this.value)) {
          jQuery(this).val('');
          return false;
   }
        var calc = parseFloat(this.value) * 0.95;
        jQuery(this).parents("form").find("input[name='price']").val(calc);
    });
```

The calculation is a constant 0.95. So I added a new input. Store name. So the user could enter the store name. The amount:

```
<input class="stores typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Stores" name="name"/>
```

And I want price to change based on both store name and amount. So I created this object:

```
var stores = {
    "McDonalds" : .90,
    "Target" : .92,
}
 var storeName = jQuery(this).parents("form").find("input[name='name']").val();
 console.log(stores[storeName]);
```

So that instead of a constant 0.95, that value can be replaced with preset values based on the store name entered. I don't know how to get those two to work together. Meaning, how do I recode the first javascript to recornize the var store values instead of 0.95?

Comment: Put the store lookup into the `change` function. Done.

Comment: `jQuery(this).val('')` is just an inefficient way to do `this.value = ''`. There is no need for *parseFloat*, `this.value * 0.95` will return a number. `jQuery(this).parents("form").find("input[name='price']").val(calc)` can be `this.form.price.value = calc`, which is hugely more efficient. jQuery isn't always less code.

Comment: Doesn't he need to use `parseFloat()` on `this.value` since `this.value` is a string, not a number? @RobG

Comment: I appreciate your feedback but this wasn't my question. I need to know how to get the change function to recognize the var store values instead of .95

Comment: @user3784824–that's why it's a comment. :-) @NobleMushtak–No, the multiplication operator `*` will convert strings to numbers (if it can). In fact is simpler to just calculate the price and see if the result is NaN rather than testing the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery("input[name='Gift-Card Amount']").change(function () {
    var amount = parseFloat(this.value);
    if (isNaN(amount) || !isFinite(amount)) {
        jQuery(this).val('');
        return false;
    }
    var storeName = jQuery(this).parents("form").find("input[name='name']").val();
    if (storeName in stores) {
        var calc = amount * stores[storeName];
        jQuery(this).parents("form").find("input[name='price']").val(calc);
    }
});
```

I also suggest that you change `Stores` from a text input to `<select>`. That way, you don't depend on the user spelling the store correctly, including capitalization.

```
<select name="name" class="storeName">
    <option value="">Please select a store</option>
    <option value=".90">McDonalds</option>
    <option value=".92">Target</option>
</select>
```

Then you can use

```
var calc = parseFloat(jQuery(this).parents("form").find(".storeName").val());
```

Comment: Where would I then put the store values?

Comment: I need to do it the other way, where a user types in the store. Later I can go back and make it alert the user they've enter an invalid store name. I like what you posted originally. I just don't know where I put my var store values now.

Comment: You can put it anywhere you want. It's just a global variable that the above function accesses.

Comment: You have no idea the migraine this has given me. And you solved it so easily. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like the following:

```
function calcPrice(element) {
  // Use the element that called the listener to find the form
  var form = element.form;
  // Access form controls as named properties of the form
  var amt = form["Gift-Card Amount"].value;

  // Don't clear the value if it's not suitable, it's annoying
  // Let the user fix it themselves
  if (parseFloat(amt) != amt) {
    alert("Gift card amount is not a suitable value")
  }

  // Set the price
  form.price.value = amt * form.store.value;
}

</script>
```

Sample form, which has all the store values. This way, you can have a fallback where the server gets all relevant values, you aren't dependent on client side calculations..

```
<form>
  Store:
  <select name="store" onchange="calcPrice(this)">
   <option value="0.90">McDonalds
   <option value="0.92">Target
  </select>
  <br>
  Gift card amount:
  <input name="Gift-Card Amount" onchange="calcPrice(this)">
  Price:
  <input name="price" readonly>
</form>
```

Comment: This isn't working for what I need it to do. I appreciate it though.

Answer (score 0):

write a little function that may return the correct value

```
function retrieveStoreValue(store){
      return stores[store];
} // be sure stores is defined before the first call of this one
```

and in your change function call it

```
var storeName = jQuery(this).parents("form").find("input[name='name']").val();

var calc = parseFloat(this.value) * (retrieveStoreValue(storeName) );
```

Comment: I want to do it this way. Where do I store the store values, .92...90, etc in the page?

Comment: the order from top is: var stores = {..} |then -> function retrieveStoreValue().. |then -> your changehandler

Comment: A function to return `stores[store]` is inefficient, just use `stores[store]`.